# VBA similar code works perfectly on one worksheet, but not the other

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code for one of my worksheets.

```
Sub Hide_Projects()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        i = 6
        For i = 6 To 350
            Cells(9, i).Select
            If Selection.Value = "Project" Then
                ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Else
                ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works fine, does exactly what I need it to every time without crashing or lagging. However, when I use a similar code on a different worksheet, only this time applied to rows rather than columns, it either crashes my Excel or takes about 2 minutes to run, even though the code is identical. This is the second code:

```
Sub Hide_Projects_5yr()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    i = 6
        For i = 6 To 350
            Cells(i, 7).Select
            If Selection.Value = "Project" Then
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

Thank you!

Comment: Your trying to hide a row thats already been hidden at some point, i could guess

Answer (score 4):

Obviously **columns** are times faster to hide than **rows**. I have tried this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestingSpeed()

    Dim lngCount    As Long
    Dim dtTime      As Date


    Columns.Hidden = False
    rows.Hidden = False

    dtTime = Now
    For lngCount = 1 To 300
        rows(lngCount).Hidden = True
    Next lngCount
    Debug.Print "Rows: -> "; DateDiff("s", dtTime, Now())

    dtTime = Now
    For lngCount = 1 To 300
        Columns(lngCount).Hidden = True
    Next lngCount
    Debug.Print "Cols: -> "; DateDiff("s", dtTime, Now())

End Sub
```

---

The result is the following (in seconds):

```
Rows: ->  9 
Cols: ->  2
```

And the difference grows somehow exponentially.

With **1.000** samples it is like this:

```
Rows: ->  11 
Cols: ->  1
```

With **10.000** like this:

```
Rows: ->  19 
Cols: ->  10
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that your active sheet is not the one you intend to work on.  It is always best to avoid `Select` and `ActiveCell`, because you are dependent on the cursor location.  Not sure you need the false case, unless you use the same sheet over and over again and it may be hidden.

```
Sub Hide_Projects_5yr()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("YourSheetName")
        For i = 6 To 350

            If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Project" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, 7).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately the code is still very slow. I think I may just have to throw in the towel for this one.

Comment: @pampk Seems odd that it would be slow.  Other ways to speed up code are to turn off automatic calculations and disable events (in the event that modifying the sheet was trigger an event).  Use `Application.Calculation =xlManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`.  Just make sure to turn back on  at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try giving your code full addresses to your cells? Besides, it is a good idea not using the select command. Here's my modifications to your code:

```
Sub Hide_Projects()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Put the name of your sheet here")
            For i = 6 To 350
                If .Cells(9, i).Text = "Project" Then
                    .Columns(i).Hidden = True
                Else
                    .Columns(i).Hidden = False
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Your second code would look like this:

```
Sub Hide_Projects_5yr()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Put the name of your second sheet here")
            For i = 6 To 350
                If .Cells(i, 7).Text = "Project" Then
                    .Rows(i).Hidden = True
                Else
                    .Rows(i).Hidden = False
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Let me know if the error message keeps appearing.

Comment: The code was definitely running on the correct sheet. The problem was the speed of the code. I've tried your code and it takes just as long. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: I get it now (also thanks to @Vityata's answer)... I always knew that hiding/showing columns was faster then hiding/showing rows. I just didn't know that the difference was that big! However, it is a little strange it took so long on a sample of less than 400 rows (I tried the code on a big file that I have and it take 5 seconds)... It could be also the Automatic Excel Calculation... Maybe you could start your code with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and end it with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`...

Answer (score 0):

Your main slowdown is a result of reading data from the worksheet too many times. Load the cell values into an array first, then loop through that.

You can also gain a bit of speed by unhiding the rows all at once at the outset, then hiding if the "="Project" condition is true. Again, this reduces the number of calls to the worksheet; your current version sets the ".Hidden" property of each row one-by-one.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Dim tempArr As Variant
tempArr = Range(Cells(6, 7), Cells(350, 7)).Value

Rows("6:350").Hidden = False

j = 1
For i = LBound(tempArr, 1) To UBound(tempArr, 1)
    If tempArr(i, 1) = "Project" Then
        Rows(j + 5).Hidden = True
    End If
    j = j + 1
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

If you're *really* concerned about speed, you could also reduce the number of trips to the worksheet by checking for consecutive rows containing "Project". This version runs ~2x as fast as the other one (tested on a sample of 200k rows). It makes the code a lot more complex, though.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim tempArr As Variant
Dim consBool As Boolean

tempArr = Range(Cells(6, 7), Cells(350, 7)).Value

Rows("6:350").Hidden = False
j = 1

For i = LBound(tempArr, 1) To UBound(tempArr, 1)
    consBool = True
    If tempArr(i, 1) = "Project" Then
        k = i
        Do Until consBool = False
            If k = UBound(tempArr, 1) Then
                consBool = False
            ElseIf tempArr(k + 1, 1) = "Project" Then
                k = k + 1
            Else
                consBool = False
            End If
        Loop
        Rows(j + 5 & ":" & k + 5).Hidden = True
        j = j + 1 + (k - i)
        i = k
    Else
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Here's what it'd look like if I were going to implement this in a larger project. Among other optimizations, I've added some features (it can check for partial matches, check multiple columns for your criteria, and do an "inverted" mode that hides all rows *not* containing your criteria) and made sure that you're required to specify your worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub exampleMacro()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Call hideRows(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Example WS"), 6, 350, "Project", 7, 7)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub hideRows(ws As Worksheet, startRow As Long, endRow As Long, valCrit As String, Optional startCol As Long = 1, Optional endCol As Long = 1, Optional invert As Boolean = False, Optional checkAll As Boolean = False)
'Hides rows in a range (startRow to endRow) in a worksheet (ws)
'Hides when row contains a value (valCrit; partial strings are accepted) in a column or series of columns (startCol to endCol)
'In inverted mode (invert), hides rows that do *not* contain value
'If (checkAll) is True, all columns must contain value to be hidden/unhidden
'Usage examples:
    'Call hideRows(exampleWS, 1, 1000, "Foo", 1, 10) -> hides rows that contain a cell in columns 1-10 with exact value "Foo"
    'Call hideRows(exampleWS, 1, 1000, "*Foo*", 1, 10) -> hides rows that contain a cell in columns 1-10 that contains partial string "*Foo*"
    'Call hideRows(exampleWS, 1, 1000, "Foo", 1, 10, True) -> hides rows that contain no cells in columns 1-10 with exact value "Foo"
    'Call hideRows(exampleWS, 1, 1000, "Foo", 1, 10, False, True) -> hides rows in which all cells in columns 1-10 contain the exact value "Foo"
    'Call hideRows(exampleWS, 1, 1000, "Foo", 1, 10, True, True) -> hides rows in which no cells in columns 1-10 contain the exact value "Foo"

    Dim loopCounter As Long
    Dim rowCounter As Long
    Dim colCounter As Long
    Dim endConsRow As Long
    Dim tempArr As Variant
    Dim toAdd As Long
    Dim toHide As String
    Dim consBool As Boolean
    Dim tempBool As Boolean
    Dim rowStr As String
    Dim goAhead As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    If startRow > endRow Then
        toAdd = endRow - 1
    Else
        toAdd = startRow - 1
    End If

    ws.Rows(startRow & ":" & endRow).Hidden = False
    tempArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, startCol), ws.Cells(endRow, endCol)).Value

    loopCounter = 1
    For rowCounter = LBound(tempArr, 1) To UBound(tempArr, 1)
        For colCounter = LBound(tempArr, 2) To UBound(tempArr, 2)
            goAhead = False
            If tempArr(rowCounter, colCounter) Like valCrit Then
                If (Not checkAll) Or (colCounter = UBound(tempArr, 2)) Then
                    If invert Then
                        loopCounter = loopCounter + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    goAhead = True
                End If
            ElseIf checkAll Or colCounter = UBound(tempArr, 2) Then
                If Not invert Then
                    loopCounter = loopCounter + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
                goAhead = True
            End If
            If goAhead Then
                endConsRow = rowCounter
                consBool = True
                Do Until consBool = False
                    tempBool = False
                    For i = LBound(tempArr, 2) To UBound(tempArr, 2)
                        If endConsRow = UBound(tempArr, 1) Then
                            Exit For
                        ElseIf tempArr(endConsRow + 1, i) Like valCrit Then
                            If (Not checkAll) Or (i = UBound(tempArr, 2)) Then
                                If Not invert Then
                                    endConsRow = endConsRow + 1
                                    tempBool = True
                                End If
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        ElseIf checkAll Or i = UBound(tempArr, 2) Then
                            If invert Then
                                endConsRow = endConsRow + 1
                                tempBool = True
                            End If
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Not tempBool Then
                        consBool = False
                    End If
                Loop
                rowStr = loopCounter + toAdd & ":" & endConsRow + toAdd
                If toHide = "" Then
                    toHide = rowStr
                ElseIf Len(toHide & "," & rowStr) > 255 Then
                    ws.Range(toHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                    toHide = rowStr
                Else
                    toHide = toHide & "," & rowStr
                End If
                loopCounter = loopCounter + 1 + (endConsRow - rowCounter)
                rowCounter = endConsRow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If Not toHide = "" Then
        ws.Range(toHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much for your help, the above code works perfectly!